# Returned xml not able to be parsed

Tags: jquery, xml, jsp

I am making an ajax call to a jsp page which returns some xml. Everything seems to go fine and when I use an alert to show the returned data everything looks fine. However, when I attempt to parse the xml in my jQuery I can not do it.

The returned xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <locations>
    <location>
      <branch>Branch</branch>
      <branchid>BranchID</branchid>
      <phone>Phone</phone>
      <address>Address</address>
      <phone2>Phone2</phone2>
      </location>
    </locations>
```

My ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.jsp",
        data: {zc : $('#zc').val()},
        async: false,            
        success: function(message){
            message = message.trim();                
            $(message).find('location').each(function(){   
                var branch = $(this).find('branch').text();
                alert(branch);
            })

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

example is:

```
var xml = "<music><album>Beethoven</album></music>";

var result = $(xml).find("album").text();
```

[For more in-depth information, read the tutorial Easy XML Consumption using jQuery](http://www.compoc.com/tuts/)

firstly get your "locations" tag :

`$(message).find('locations').find('location')`

Comment: I tried this. I then did a .find('location').each() and it still will not show the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.parseXML

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );
```

For reference: [jQuery parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 0):

please try  next code:

```
var message = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>"
  +"<locations>"
    +"<location>"
      +"<branch>Branch</branch>"
      +"<branchid>BranchID</branchid>"
      +"<phone>Phone</phone>"
      +"<address>Address</address>"
      +"<phone2>Phone2</phone2>"
      +"</location>"
    +"</locations>";

 $('location', message).each(function(xml){
     console.log( 'branch:' +$(this).find('phone2').text());
     console.log( 'branchid:' +$(this).find('branchid').text());
     console.log( 'phone:' +$(this).find('phone').text());
     console.log( 'address:' +$(this).find('address').text());
 })
```